# BCP IN Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Invalid date format on a particular server

Tags: sql-server, date, format, bcp

I'm facing a BCP import fails problem with this error only on one server :

/!\ SQLState = 22008, NativeError = 0|
/!\ Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Invalid date format|

My script works on 2 servers but not on the third.

I'm using a XML mapping file with this declared :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
....
<FIELD ID="16" xsi:type="NativeFixed" LENGTH="23"/>
...
</RECORD>
<ROW>
...
<COLUMN SOURCE="16" NAME="ENDDATETIME" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="23" />
...
</ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

The only difference is the database server used, it's the same for the 2 servers, and a different for the third.

Have you any idea ? I tried with the -R switch, but it has no effect.

Linked topic : [BCP IN Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Invalid date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405052/bcp-in-error-microsoftsql-server-native-client-10-0invalid-date-format/23613128#23613128)

Thanks

Comment: Are all three servers configured precisely the same?  Are they all the same version of SQL Server?  Are the regional settings on the non-working server exactly the same as the regional settings on the working servers?  (Regional Settings in the Windows Control Panel applet).

Comment: No one server is on Windows 7 Enterprise, another on Windows Server 2008 R2. SQL Server version is 10.50.4000 on which it works and 10.50.4286 on which it doesn't works. The DB user's language is english on both servers. I will ask windows regional settings configuration.

Comment: I changed the sql datatype from datetime to varchar(23). It seems that on the non-working server, bcp doesn't parse the right field. Offset -7 chars.

Comment: Changing the field to `VARCHAR(23)` will only create further problems.  Did you check the Regional Settings to see if they match on working and non-working servers?

Comment: I asked for configuration but I did not get it yet. Why will varchar(23) create other problems ? The date retrieved in the field is :     5502014-05-01 02:56 and 2014-05-01 02:56:59.000 one date is parsed correctly (at the beginning of the line in the file) the second not.

Comment: Ok I found a workarroung, it seems that on the server the format file is interpreted differently. I added a 7 chars column in the format file and now it works, the date is converted correctly. Why is the format file interpreted differently on one server ? Thanks

Comment: Without knowing the configuration of the server, it is impossible to know.